# Could you recommend an IDE that is suitable for writing and running C, C++, C#?

Tags: c++, c, ide, macos

Could you recommend an IDE that is suitable for writing and running C, C++, C# and works, can write code, run code out of the box on macos Catalina?

Comment: I don't think there's one IDE that encompasses all of these. Why so many languages?

Comment: @S.S.Anne: Visual Studio can do this on Windows. Why shouldn't something similar exist on macOS?

Answer (score 1):

If you need one IDE for multiple languages then a good bet is [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) is supports almost every programming language and multiple platforms with plugins for many languages, (it also has the user interface supporting 44 or more human languages).

- It is available free and is licenced under the Eclipse Public
  Licence.
- Supports multiple tool chains for the compilation and for
  debugging.
- During running the installation you are offered a choice
  of your primary language(s) to support

[image]

- After installation you can add multiple plug-in tools
- There are a huge number of options that you can set
- You can interface into almost any set of build & debug tools
- You may need to download and install either the Java SDK or RTE.

Answer (score 0):

Try CLion. It's made by Jetbrains. It isn't free but it may just be what you are looking for.

https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/features/

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/) is available. Formally known as Xamarin Studio.